# Can i set value in multiple input in PHP?

Tags: php, html, input

Can I do something like this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="for_person[]" miltiple="multiple" value="<?php echo $request_control['personal_task']; ?>">
```

I guess not, cause output in `value=""` tag is "Array" of course.

Comment: $request_control['personal_task'] = output from multiple input one step before (is array)

Comment: I like miltiple inputs

Comment: Start with the purpose. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Brian miltiple is my new fav word

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="miltiple" value="<?php echo implode(',', $array); ?>">` then `explode()` the value after it's submitted.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - search the definition of milt :)

Comment: @Brian yummy :D Well I like caviar but I'd not try milt :S

Comment: I refill hidden form when I need control data from form before. I print POST to table because I need control and catch mistakes. And when user click on submit second time the hidden form substitute the first form and i send filter_input_array as parametr to function which add this data to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improvise for something like this:

```
<?php foreach($request_control['personal_task'] as $task): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="for_person[]" multiple="multiple" 
        value="<?= $task ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set miltiple values for a name using miltiple inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="for_person[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="for_person[]" value="2">
```

Just loop over your array using `foreach` or `while` or `for`....

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to produce a string outof the array and pass via the hidden input. At server you can get it back via [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Like

```
<input type="hidden" name="for_person" value="<?php echo json_encode($request_control['personal_task']); ?>" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="for_person" value="<?php echo serialize($request_control['personal_task']); ?>" />
```